# AbstractThreadedSyncAdapter triggers every minute even if I have set up an hourly interval

Tags: java, android, synchronization, android-contentprovider, android-syncadapter

I have created a class that extends AbstractThreadedSyncAdapter and have followed all guidelines in the official Android documentations.

Here are some snippets:

```
    public class MySyncAdapter extends AbstractThreadedSyncAdapter {

    // 60 seconds (1 minute) * 180 = 3 hours
    public static final int SYNC_INTERVAL = 60 * 180;
    public static final int SYNC_FLEXTIME = SYNC_INTERVAL / 5;


    public MySyncAdapter(Context context, boolean autoInitialize) {
        super(context, autoInitialize);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPerformSync(Account account, Bundle extras, String authority, ContentProviderClient provider, SyncResult syncResult) {
        Log.w(LOG_TAG, "Starting sync");
        // DATA DOWNLOAD/UPLOAD LOGIC HERE

    }

    /**
     * Helper method to get the fake account to be used with SyncAdapter, or make a new one
     * if the fake account doesn't exist yet.  If we make a new account, we call the
     * onAccountCreated method so we can initialize things.
     *
     * @param context The context used to access the account service
     * @return a fake account.
     */
    public static Account getSyncAccount(Context context) {
        // Get an instance of the Android account manager
        AccountManager accountManager =
                (AccountManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ACCOUNT_SERVICE);

        // Create the account type and default account
        Account newAccount = new Account(
                context.getString(R.string.app_name), context.getString(R.string.sync_account_type));

        // If the password doesn't exist, the account doesn't exist
        if ( null == accountManager.getPassword(newAccount) ) {

        /*
         * Add the account and account type, no password or user data
         * If successful, return the Account object, otherwise report an error.
         */
            if (!accountManager.addAccountExplicitly(newAccount, "", null)) {
                return null;
            }
            /*
             * If you don't set android:syncable="true" in
             * in your <provider> element in the manifest,
             * then call ContentResolver.setIsSyncable(account, AUTHORITY, 1)
             * here.
             */

            onAccountCreated(newAccount, context);
        }
        return newAccount;
    }

    private static void onAccountCreated(Account newAccount, Context context) {
        /*
         * Since we've created an account
         */
        MySyncAdapter.configurePeriodicSync(context, SYNC_INTERVAL, SYNC_FLEXTIME);

        /*
         * Without calling setSyncAutomatically, our periodic sync will not be enabled.
         */
        ContentResolver.setSyncAutomatically(newAccount, context.getString(R.string.content_authority), true);

        /*
         * Finally, let's do a sync to get things started
         */
        syncImmediately(context);
    }

/**
     * Helper method to schedule the sync adapter periodic execution
     */
    public static void configurePeriodicSync(Context context, int syncInterval, int flexTime) {
        Account account = getSyncAccount(context);
        String authority = context.getString(R.string.content_authority);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
            // we can enable inexact timers in our periodic sync
            SyncRequest request = new SyncRequest.Builder().
                    syncPeriodic(syncInterval, flexTime).
                    setSyncAdapter(account, authority).
                    setExtras(new Bundle()).build();
            ContentResolver.requestSync(request);
        } else {
            ContentResolver.addPeriodicSync(account,
                    authority, new Bundle(), syncInterval);
        }
    }

    public static void initializeSyncAdapter(Context context) {
        getSyncAccount(context);
    }

}
```

I logged the sync triggers on Logcat and have found out that the sync happens every minute which is so weird since I've set an interval of every 3 hours.

Comment: where is `addPeriodicSync` called?

Comment: @pskink Sorry forgot to add the method since I was cleaning up the code from unneccesarry methods to show, I've edited the question with the configurePeriodicSync which contains the addPeriodicSync.

Comment: Both methods you are using to register sync state: pollFrequency - long: how frequently the sync should be performed, in seconds. *A minimum value of 1 hour is enforced*. So if you sync is running every minute the issue is somewhere else in your code.